# How to make an HTML element fit between two others?

Tags: html, css

How do I make an HTML element fit evenly between two others?
Example: [My Website](http://thedoorgame.otabi.com)

I want my `<div>` with my Doge picture in it to fit evenly between my `<ul>` and my Twitter widget. My widget is fixed width and my `<ul>` is fixed width, my `.news` being a percentage of the screen width (the space left between). I don't want to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Wrap your `ul`, `div` & `iframe` in one container and give your container a width. After that, give your `ul`, `div` & `iframe` a width of 33.3333333%.